# How to Reverse Values in Map <String, List<String>> Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, reverse

I have

```
Map<String,List<String>> myMap = {'1': ['A','B','C'], '2': ['D','E','F'], '3': ['G','H','I'] };
```

I would like to know how I can reverse the list values. This is what I want to achieve:

```
Map<String,List<String>> myMap = {'1': ['C','B','A'], '2': ['F','E','D'], '3': ['I','H','G'] };
```

Comment: in a loop reversed.toList will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this :**

```
 void main() {
      Map<String,List<String>> myMap = {'1': ['A','B','C'], '2': ['D','E','F'], '3': ['G','H','I'] };
      
      Map<String,List<String>> reversedMap = {}; 
      
      myMap.forEach((key,value) {
        reversedMap[key] = value.reversed.toList();
      });
      
      print(reversedMap);
    }
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
{1: [C, B, A], 2: [F, E, D], 3: [I, H, G]}
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of using `for (var e in myMap.entries) { .. }` for something like that, instead of the `forEach`, which offers more options like breaking the loop after some conditions, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
data.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.reversed.toList()));
```

Note: this produce a new map. See more in comment.

Comment: Note that this will produce a new `Map` and not mutate the original.